# Nginx configuration with Magento 1.8

Tags: mysql, nginx, fastcgi, magento

anybody knows how to configure server {} in configuration file of nginx server?
I have something like this below:

```
server {
  server_name   local.com;

  root some_path;

  index index.php;

  #location / {
    #try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
    #proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:9000;
  #}

  # set a nice expire for assets
  #location ~* "^.+\.(jpe?g|gif|css|png|js|ico|pdf|zip|tar|t?gz|mp3|wav|swf)$" {
  #  expires    max;
  #  add_header Cache-Control public;
  #}

  # the downloader has its own index.php that needs to be used
  #location ~* ^(/downloader|/js|/404|/report)(.*) {
  #  include fastcgi_params;
  #  fastcgi_index index.php;
  #  fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$1/index.php$1;
  #  fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
  #  fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
  #}

  location ~* \.php {
    include               fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param         SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_read_timeout  18000;
    fastcgi_pass          127.0.0.1:9000;
  }

  #location ~* ^(/index.php)?(.*) {
  #  include               fastcgi_params;
  #  fastcgi_param         SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/index.php$1;
  #  fastcgi_pass          127.0.0.1:9000;
  #  fastcgi_read_timeout  18000;
  #}

}
```

Browser returns blank page and doesn't exec php...

EDIT:

After spending some time with nginx configuration and php stuff i ended on having site that in some cases load properly and in some not...

Ex:
I have two pages that are identical, but for some reason first is loading lie a charm, and second is loading partially...

Sometimes page is loading half way...

Nginx isn't logging anything...

And for some reason when i try to go to backend, nginx loads frontend with backend url :/

Does anybody can provide me with other magento 1.8 configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it wasn't memory or database issue, it was... IonCube issue... i was debuging core classes and found that script stops on Enteprise Modules and... if You don't have IonCube installed it just simply display blank page.

But, now Magento returns 404: Page not found...

Thx, guys for help and if You have some advice on second issue fell free to post it here :)

After applying little fix:

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';
/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';
Mage::run('', 'store'); //<-this
//Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

Front and Back are loading, but there is an problem with controllers... but not for long !

A and if i type in url /admin nginx will return Input file not found, but when i type index.php/admin it load... part. It's and issue with rewrite and server vars.

EDIT:

I won ! iconv wasn't installed... now everything work except rewriting...

SUMMARY:
I need to find a way to properly get server var for index.php file and rewrite index.php to /

Thx for help !

Comment: location / {
   index index.php;
   if (!-e $request_filename) {
      rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php last;
   }
   try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
}

Put this for redirection from index.php to /

Comment: And for the server vars:
fastcgi_param         MAGE_RUN_CODE code;
fastcgi_param         MAGE_RUN_TYPE type;

And we can then in code use $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'], before it did't work cause i had other issues with nginx configuration.

Answer (score 1):

After the `index` directive (actually it doesn't matter where, it's just for legibility) add a [try_files](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#try_files) directive.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
```

By chance I wrote a fuller guide on this: [Configuring nginx for Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/configuring_nginx_for_magento)

Comment: Thx, for help Your tutorial clarify some points in nginx, but still i can't force nginx to properly exec file in my domain.

Comment: I didn't look at the commented-out part before and missed that you had done try_files previously.

Comment: If PHP files execute correctly but then run out of memory they can return a blank page. This happens with Magento because it overrides normal error reporting and is very memory intensive. Have you tried creating a file with just `<?php phpinfo();` and accessing that?

Comment: I did put phpinfo() at the beginning of the index.php, but still it's blank page. Funny thing is, that when i installed nginx first time, everything before Mage::run(...) was executed, ex: phpinfo()

Comment: Sorry I don't know another cause of a blank page. If anything else was wrong it would give a "Bad Gateway" or "Input file not specified" error.

Comment: Thx anyway :)
Sometimes when i try to go to admin i get "input file...". "Bad Gateway" i get only when fastcgi isn't active.

I tested nginx on pure Zend Framework site and everything works |-(

Comment: The reason admin doesn't work is because initially nginx does not know how to handle paths like `/index.php/admin`. That is something addressed in the guide. Perhaps the index.php has lost it's read permissions...

Comment: Permissions are good.

I have found something, when magento invoke run method, it invokes also this thing Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()... it executes about 109 loops in foreach and then stops with now reason :/ after that ther is a code, but it isn't executed...

Comment: the `applyAllUpdates()` method is updating your database with the latest data structures for each of the modules.  It sounds like it might be a database timeout that is causing the issue.  Can you increase the timeout value in nginx?

Comment: The nginx timeout above is 18000 seconds, or 5 hours, so it probably won't be that. My instinct still says "running out of memory".

Comment: Memory limit and database timout... well i don't think it's that, cause i created php.ini for nginx from my php.ini from apache, on apache everything works with that configuration.
MySQL server was compiled long time ago, and for ex: with VERY big Magento project it worked fine.

For some reason nginx or php can't go after this loop:

foreach ($resources as $resName=>$resource) { ... } in Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates() method.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the latter questions about MAGE_RUN_CODE you can do it with the nginx map.  See: [Coeus Blue Blog Post](http://www.coeusblue.com/blog/48-magento/68-nginxmagentomultisite)