# nginx multistore magento

Tags: magento, nginx

I'm looking for a way to setup Nginx in a Multi Store environment on Magento. I have setup the server + Nginx, added domains and that all works great.

Unfortunately, the adjustments that normally are made in .htaccess don't work. I'm not sure where to add this (index.php?). So my question is: how to setup multistore using multiurl?

(Yes: i've tried the Magento manual, but it says nothing about multistore)

Comment: Nginx doesn't support htaccess files, so you'll need to do it all in the conf file for your vhost (or `server` as Nginx calls it)

Answer (score 7):

If you mean setting the store code per store, you can use the HTTPMapModule.

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMapModule.

E.g. for domain per store:

```
map $http_host $storecode {
    domain.com store1code;
}
...

fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE $storecode;
```

*Waves at Ben Marks.

Comment: make sure that you use a uniquely named variable for $storecode if you are in a shared hosting environment. Nginx seems to create those variables in a global context, so call it something like <vhost>storecode

Answer (score 1):

You *could* add your switching logic to index.php, but that file is designed to remain unmodified for production environments. You need to pass environment variables in to trigger the loading of the correct store configuration (`$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']`).

In Apache configs this is done using `mod_env` and `SetEnv` / `SetEnvIf`. You need to do the analogous in nginx, and do so according to your needs. For nginx the analogous method to `SetEnv` is `fastcgi_param`.

[This seems relevant (3rd comment).](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4358615/833795)

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer to the post 
[Nginx - Magento multiple websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213255/nginx-magento-multiple-websites)

This explains with an example.