# Nginx - Magento multiple websites

Tags: .htaccess, magento, nginx, webserver

I have a Magento installation with multiple websites, which is running in Apache web server.
Now I want to move these to Nginx web server; how can I achieve this with Nginx configuration?
Below is the htaccess code which is redirecting websites:

```
SetEnvIf HOST 44\.55\.222\.101\:8080 MAGE_RUN_CODE=website_new
SetEnvIf HOST 44\.55\.222\.101\:8080 MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run 2 Magento websites on the same server with different ports you bave to use 2 different nginx configuration files for each port under `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`.

From the example provided it seems like you are running the websites on ports 80 and 8080. The Magento has provided the default nginx configuration here at http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/configuring_nginx_for_magento

Use this for port 80 and for 8080 use the below code:

```
server {
    listen 8080 default;
    server_name 44.55.222.101; 
    root /var/www/html;
    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
        expires 30d;
    }
    location ^~ /app/ { deny all; }
    location ^~ /includes/           { deny all; }
    location ^~ /lib/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
    location ^~ /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
    location ^~ /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
    location ^~ /var/                { deny all; }
    location /var/export/ {
        auth_basic           "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file htpasswd;
        autoindex            on;
    }
    location  /. {
        return 404;
    }
    location @handler {
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }
    location ~ .php/ {
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }
    location ~ .php$ {
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } 
        expires        off;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE website_new; 
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE website;
        include        fastcgi_params; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, we have added more info on how to do this (logic behind it) in this article - http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/set-multiple-magento-2-websites-stores-nginx/

Answer (score 2):

Store code is defined in Administration > Configuration > Manage Stores

```
fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
```

Answer (score -1):

`.htaccess` and `SetEnvIf` is for Apache web server. For Nginx you can use `fastcgi_param` (if you are running nginx with fastcgi).

You can find more details here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/configuring_nginx_for_magento